# How to remove the ToolTip (Press F1 for more Help) from my word Addin

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, tooltip

Currently i am working on an addin, in which i am having a Ribbon.In that Ribbon, If i move the mouse over any button I am getting my Feature description(description of that button) as well as Screen tip(my Addin name,Press F1 for more Help).

my question is how to remove this Screen tip "**Press F1 for more Help**".

Any help can be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, you can't: see this thread on the [VSTO forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/fd820223-f947-4c10-a3df-902e98c596ab/)

Comment: Painful stupidity is common thing when dealing with MS

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't remove it, you can edit it by

Project Properties -> Publish -> Options -> office setting

(VS2013)