# Remove Office 2013 Addin Tooltip

Tags: add-in, ribbon, office-2013

Does anybody know how I can remove the Enhanced Tooltip from a custom Office 2013 addin?

I have the same Ribbon.xml description for my own tab that I use in an Office 2010 Addin.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide more details in order to get useful help, though. Can you show us the code in Ribbon.xml? Have you developed both addins? In what environment are you working? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of [How to remove the ToolTip (Press F1 for more Help) from my word Addin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139785/how-to-remove-the-tooltip-press-f1-for-more-help-from-my-word-addin)

In short, you cannot remove the tooltip, it is a design decision by [Microsoft](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/fd820223-f947-4c10-a3df-902e98c596ab/).